# Getting differences between two directories with full details

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, files

I have two directories and i need their differences output in this format

example :

```
DIR1 conatins :   file1
                  file2
                  file3
DIR2 contains :   file1
                  file4
```

Output (only filenames, no file contents):  file1 is modified or same, file2 is removed, file4 is added

Comment: Would [meld](https://meldmerge.org/) work for you?

Answer (score 1):

That's a simple one, check out the popular tool `diff`:
`diff -r dir1 dir2`
Edit: I got OP's question wrong, to get only the information **that** the files differ, not **how** they differ, you need to use the `-q` option:
`diff -r -q dir1 dir2`

Comment: it will show contents which changes .. i only need the file names

Comment: @yugandhar Sorry, I got that wrong. Does my edit solve your question now?

Answer (score 0):

Emulating how tools such as `comm` or `join` would compare two sets of sorted input, using `bash`:

```bash
# Get lists of (base-)names from both directories.
files1=( dir1/* ); files1=( "${files1[@]##*/}" )
files2=( dir2/* ); files2=( "${files2[@]##*/}" )

# Loop over these sorted lists until one of them is empty.
while [[ ${#files1[@]} -gt 0 ]] && [[ ${#files2[@]} -gt 0 ]]; do
        name1=${files1[0]}
        name2=${files2[0]}

        if [[ $name1 == "$name2" ]]; then
                # Name exists in both directories.
                printf '%s is modified or same\n' "$name1"
                files1=( "${files1[@]:1}" )
                files2=( "${files2[@]:1}" )
        elif [[ $name1 < $name2 ]]; then
                # Name exists in only first directory.
                printf '%s is removed\n' "$name1"
                files1=( "${files1[@]:1}" )
        else
                # Name exists in only second directory.
                printf '%s is added\n' "$name2"
                files2=( "${files2[@]:1}" )
        fi
done

# Handle remaining names.
if [[ ${#files1[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
        printf '%s is removed\n' "${files1[@]}"
fi
if [[ ${#files2[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
        printf '%s is added\n' "${files2[@]}"
fi
```

I'm using two `bash` arrays to hold the names found in each directory, and then I iterate until one of these arrays is empty.

In the loop, I compare the first name of each array with each other. If the names are the same, then the file is the same or has possibly been modified (the name is then removed from both arrays).

If the  name from the first array sorts before the name from the second array (tested with `<`), then the first name is missing from the second directory. Now delete the first element of the first array.

Otherwise, the name from the second array is missing from the first directory. Now delete the first element of the second array.

After the loop, one of the arrays may still be non-empty, so output the names from that array if needed.